# Java, is this thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading

I am a beginner in concurrency, so I'd be nice if somebody will check this code.

I have a list and instead of locking the whole list I lock first element, then lock second element, move to second element, release lock from first element and so on.

```
public class List {
    private Node head;
    private Random random = new Random();

    public List(int o) {
        this.head = new Node(o);
    }

    public void addToList(int o) {      
        Node actual = head;
        actual.setLock();
        Node next;
        while( (next = actual.next() )!= null) {
            next.setLock();
            System.out.println(actual.getElement());
            actual.unlock();
            actual = next;

        }
        Node newNode = new Node(random.nextInt());
        newNode.setLock();
        actual.setNext(newNode);
        actual.unlock();
        newNode.unlock();
    }

    public void printList() {
        Node actual = head;
        actual.setLock();
        Node next;
        while( (next = actual.next() )!= null) {
            next.setLock();
            System.out.println(actual.getElement());
            actual.unlock();
            actual = next;

        }
        System.out.println(actual.getElement());
        actual.unlock();
    }
}
```

and Node class

```
public class Node {
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final int element;
    private Node next = null;

    public Node(int element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    public int getElement() {
       try {
           lock.lock();
           return element;
       } finally {
           lock.unlock();
       }
    }

    public Node next() {
        try {
            lock.lock();
            return next;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void setLock() {
        lock.lock();
    }

    public void unlock() {
        lock.unlock();
    }

    public void setNext(Node node) {
        try {
            lock.lock();
            next = node;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

I know that I can use list from library, but I want to understand how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safe in terms of the Java memory model but it's very error-prone. Managing so many things, it is very likely a mistake will be made. Already I see that you are using the `finally...unlock` idiom only sometimes (I assume because putting it in the loop is complicated) and this is the type of thing I mean.

Acquiring so many locks is also a comparatively expensive way to do concurrent programming. Also not memory efficient since you need an extra object for each Node.

There is a minor thing as well which is that the Node element is not assigned under its own lock:

```
public Node(int element) {
    this.element = element;
}
```

A lock is held on the previous Node but that means technically the list needs to be traversed to ensure the assigned element is seen.

The way that locking works vis-a-vis memory consistency, when a lock is acquired, the actions that are guaranteed to be visible are only the actions taken *while that particular lock was held* (and actions leading up to those).

Right now when you create a new Node, what it does is this:

```
actual.lock();
Node newNode = new Node(random.nextInt());
...
actual.unlock();
```

This means that the lock that was held while assigning the element in `newNode` was the lock on `actual`. So for another thread to be guaranteed to see the correct value for the `newNode`, it needs to acquire the lock for `actual`. (And this would happen if the list is traversed.)

Though actually looking at it again I see `element` is declared to be final so visibility of it should be guaranteed without the lock. Also you do acquire and release the lock for `newNode` immediately after constructing it. But this is the kind of complicated interaction to be aware of.

If `element` were not final you would just do this:

```
public Node(int element) {
    lock.lock();
    try {
        this.element = element;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

The error-prone nature of managing so many locks is the more important downside I wanted to point out. At the moment you've only got 2 methods, but for example `java.util.List` has around 20. If you were to fully implement List, it is a lot of code to get right.

Comment: Thank you for comment. Could you explain me last two sentences in other words, because I have difficulty in understanding it. Should I use setter instead of constructor ?

Comment: See my edit, though I see now that `element` is final so it's definitely OK.

Comment: I used finally .. unlock because there is a return statement, so I wanted to unlock lock before leaving the method and finally can guarantee this

Comment: Well putting unlock inside finally is actually the preferred way to use a Lock, as shown in the [Lock documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html). It ensures that unlock is called even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: And what do you think about this while loop. I check if next element isnt null. If true I acquire lock. Is it possible that this element change will be deleted between these operations ( I have delete method also )

Comment: It could be there is a way for an interleave to happen where one thread appends a new Node to a Node that is being deleted by another thread. (Thus accidentally deleting the new node as well.) It depends on what your delete method does. As long as you are acquiring the lock on the node you are deleting (and probably the adjacent Nodes), I don't see how it would be a problem at the moment. Very tricky though.